# Full upgrade in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

what means the item "Apply full Upgrade" under the main menu/preferences in Lubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2):

It's a *desktop entry* which can be view via *right-click* and *copy* using the mouse, then pasting the contents into a text editor (eg. `featherpad`).

What you'll see is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=lxqt-sudo /usr/bin/lubuntu-upgrader --cache-update --full-upgrade
Name=Apply Full Upgrade
GenericName=Apply Full Upgrade
Comment=Search and Apply Full Upgrade
Icon=system-software-update
Type=Application
Version=0.1
Categories=System;Settings;
Keywords=upgrade;update
Terminal=false
```

ie.  it'll execute

`lxqt-sudo /usr/bin/lubuntu-upgrader --cache-update --full-upgrade`

ie. it'll ask for your password (*in a GUI dialog*) and do the equivalent of `sudo apt update` to update your software lists (*cached data*) then perform an `apt full-upgrade` with the output appearing in dialog window on screen. You'll be told if you should reboot & allowed to close the window.

*Do note:  I've used my own system to grab the contents of that file; yours may differ slightly as my release is later than Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.*